# IB_DESIGNABLE using attributed strings

Tags: objective-c, ios8, interface-builder, nsattributedstring, ibdesignable

I am using IB_DESIGNABLE on a UIView subclass because I want to be able to make an attributed string programmatically, but have it appear in Interface builder (saving me from having to run the app to see the formatting)

I've been told that I can put my code into

```
- (void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder;
```

And it works to a certain degree.  it appears in interface builder.  But when I go to run the APP the formatting is lost.  It still appears in Interface builder, but not in the app.

Below are the methods I have tried using to create my Attributed String, but they do not appear in interface builder nor when the app is run.

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)frame;
```

However, with that said I have found a method that will render in the APP but not in interface builder.

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;
```

With that said, the solution would be to just use BOTH methods.  However I was wondering if there was another method that would take the best of both worlds.

Also, I'll add a code snippet to show what I am doing and to offer some completion to this query.

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface FooLabel1 : UILabel
@property (nonatomic, copy) IBInspectable NSAttributedString *attributedText;
@end

@implementation FooLabel1

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self localizeattributedString];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)localizeattributedString {
    NSMutableAttributedString *mat = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(
            @"Hello"
            @"Darkness my old friend"
         , nil) attributes:@{
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor orangeColor],
    }];
    [mat appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"world!", nil) attributes:@{
            NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:60],
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor]
    }]];
    self.attributedText = [mat autorelease];
}

- (void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder {
    [self localizeattributedString];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution in your question works properly, but for the wrong reasons. What you want to do is call your configuration method (`localizeattributedString`) from both `initWithCoder:` and `initWithFrame:`, as below.

`prepareForInterfaceBuilder` is a special method that *only* gets called in the context of rendering an `IB_DESIGNABLE` view. For example, if normally a custom view gets part of its data from a web service, in `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` you would just provide example data instead.

```
@implementation FooLabel1

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self localizeattributedString];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self localizeattributedString];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)localizeattributedString {
    ...
}

@end
```